# How to fetch data from Google Apps Script from a server?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a Google Apps Script endpoint that sends a json response after signing in with a custom google account. Eg. abc@company.co.in

I have another server in which I want that json response after hitting the google apps script endpoint.

I tried using oauth2 but it again redirects to the google sign-in screen to get the response. I need to automate the sign-in so that there is no need to sign in again and again.